# Multiple Like Columns in Query

Tags: sql, codeigniter, sql-like

I'm using CodeIgniter 2.1.

I have a table which have firstname and lastname and other columns
I want to get those customers which have `firstname like '%q%' OR lastname like '%q' AND Status = 1`

I'm using the following Active Record set:

```
$this->db->select("$this->table.*, $this->table.Active as 'Status'");
$like = array(
 "$this->table.FirstName" => $where['customer_name'],
 "$this->table.LastName" => $where['customer_name']
);
$this->db->or_like($like);
```

The generated query is:

```
SELECT `customers`.*, `customers`.`Active` as 'Status' 
WHERE `customers`.`Active` = '1' AND 
      `customers`.`FirstName` LIKE '%michael%' OR 
      `customers`.`LastName` LIKE '%michael%' 
ORDER BY `customers`.`RegDate` desc LIMIT 10
```

Above query brings those customers which have 'michael' either in first name or last name AND active = 1, it brings all the records which have michael either they are active or not.

I need those record which have 'micheal' in firstname or lastname AND active = 1, I know in custom query, if I place Like clause between small brace ' ()', it will give me my desired result.
I want the above query to be parse as:

```
SELECT `customers`.*, `customers`.`Active` as 'Status' 
WHERE `customers`.`Active` = '1' AND 
      (`customers`.`FirstName` LIKE '%michael%' OR 
      `customers`.`LastName` LIKE '%michael%') 
       ORDER BY `customers`.`RegDate` desc LIMIT 10
```

Comment: where is the table name and `from` clause in query ? did you forget `$this->db-get()` ?

Comment: dear, I am doing everything, the code is just for example, what I want to place the like conditions within the small braces. any idea ? $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
        $query = $this->db->get($this->table);

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to also make use of the [or_where](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html) function

Comment: I also did that, but what I want is not accomplished, I think I have to go for $this->db->query() as i'm running out of time ... thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The grouping does not come proper when putting where and or_like with multiple columns in codeigniter .
I too faced this issue,

The best solution is to write the query in the string format and then execute it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //You can used like that 

$this->db->where("(`car_model` LIKE '%$search_keyword_new%' OR  `car_make_model` LIKE '%$search_keyword_new%' OR `car_name` LIKE '%$search_keyword_new%')");
$this->db->where('user_id',$user_id);
```